# linq and asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

```
   bool flagemployee = employee == null ? true : false;
        bool flagcompany = company == null ? true : false;
        bool flaglocation = location == null ? true : false;
        bool flagdivision = division == null ? true : false;
        bool flagdepartment = department == null ? true : false;
        bool flagdesignation = designation == null ? true : false;
        bool flaggrade = grade == null ? true : false;
        bool flaggrop = grop == null ? true : false;
        bool flagcategory = category == null ? true : false;


        try{
        var obj = (from epd in dev.ENT_EMPLOYEE_PERSONAL_DTLS
                   join eod in dev.ENT_EMPLOYEE_OFFICIAL_DTLS on epd.EPD_EMPID equals eod.EOD_EMPID
                   join com in dev.ENT_COMPANY on eod.EOD_COMPANY_ID equals com.COMPANY_ID
                   join loc in dev.ENT_ORG_COMMON_ENTITIES on new { X1 = eod.EOD_LOCATION_ID, X2 = "LOC" } equals new { X1 = loc.OCE_ID, X2 = loc.CEM_ENTITY_ID }
                   join div in dev.ENT_ORG_COMMON_ENTITIES on new { X1 = eod.EOD_DIVISION_ID, X2 = "DIV" } equals new { X1 = div.OCE_ID, X2 = div.CEM_ENTITY_ID }
                   join dep in dev.ENT_ORG_COMMON_ENTITIES on new { X1 = eod.EOD_DEPARTMENT_ID, X2 = "DEP" } equals new { X1 = dep.OCE_ID, X2 = dep.CEM_ENTITY_ID }
                   join des in dev.ENT_ORG_COMMON_ENTITIES on new { X1 = eod.EOD_DESIGNATION_ID, X2 = "DES" } equals new { X1 = des.OCE_ID, X2 = des.CEM_ENTITY_ID }
                   join grd in dev.ENT_ORG_COMMON_ENTITIES on new { X1 = eod.EOD_GRADE_ID, X2 = "GRD" } equals new { X1 = grd.OCE_ID, X2 = grd.CEM_ENTITY_ID }
                   join grp in dev.ENT_ORG_COMMON_ENTITIES on new { X1 = eod.EOD_GROUP_ID, X2 = "GRP" } equals new { X1 = grp.OCE_ID, X2 = grp.CEM_ENTITY_ID }
                   join cat in dev.ENT_ORG_COMMON_ENTITIES on new { X1 = eod.EOD_CATEGORY_ID, X2 = "CAT" } equals new { X1 = cat.OCE_ID, X2 = cat.CEM_ENTITY_ID }
                   where
                   flagemployee ? 1 == 1 : employee.Contains(epd.EPD_EMPID) 
                   && flagcompany == true ? 1 == 1 : company.Contains(eod.EOD_COMPANY_ID)
```

now am maintaning flag for employee or location if employee is null then it will return flag true and result will be 1==1 same for employee also but getting following error "An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking about this line of code

```
(location.i ==null? 1==1 : location.Contains(eod.EOD_LOCATION_ID))
```

which should be written as

```
(location.i == null || location.Contains(eod.EOD_LOCATION_ID))
```

where `||` means `or`.